# Get Scientific Buttons Clear Before New Value

Tags: java, javafx, calculator

This might be a duplicate to my other question: [JavaFX Calculator Doesn't Clear After Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100504/javafx-calculator-doesnt-clear-after-answer)

I've made a scientific calculator with Javafx/Java, but the "Scientific" buttons, such as tan, or cos, or square root have a problem clearing. The add, subtract, multiply, and divide buttons work fine.

Ex): Say I did 2 + 2, then pressed = and got 4. If I pressed another number, it would clear first, not just add onto the number like this: 45 But like this: 5 And if I pressed +/-/// button, it would clear the text area, too of course, so that the user could put in another number.

Ex) Say I did 16 , then pressed square root and got 4. If I pressed another number, it would just add onto the original number like this: 323 Not like this: 3 That's the problem with all the other scientific buttons, too.

I did trigger the same thing for the scientific/+, -, etc. to clear before a new value comes in after the answer, so I don't know the problem here.

```java
else if(event.getSource() == cos)
        {
            data = Float.parseFloat(display.getText());
            Double ans = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(data));
            display.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
            dot.setDisable(false);  
            if(event.getSource() != divide && event.getSource() != add && event.getSource() != multi && event.getSource() != minus && event.getSource() != pow && event.getSource() != mod)
            {
                start = true;
            } 
        }
```

Here's the 'start' code:

```java
        private boolean start = false;
        if(start)
        {
            data = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
            start = false;
        }
```

And how I did it with the +, -, etc. buttons:

```java
        else if(event.getSource() == equals)
        {
            Double secondOperand = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
            dot.setDisable(false);
            switch(operation)
            {
                case 1: //Addition
                    Double ans = data + secondOperand;
                    display.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
                    break;
                case 2: //Subtraction
                    ans = data - secondOperand;
                    display.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
                    break;
                case 3: //Multiplication
                    ans = data * secondOperand;
                    display.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
                    break;
                case 4: //Division
                    ans = 0d;
                    try{
                    ans = data / secondOperand;
                    }catch(Exception ex){display.setText("Error");}
                    display.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
                    break;
                case 5:
                    ans = data % secondOperand;
                    display.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
                    break;
                case 6:
                    ans = Math.pow(data, secondOperand);
                    display.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
                    break;

            }
            operation = -1;
            if(event.getSource() != divide && event.getSource() != add && event.getSource() != multi && event.getSource() != minus && event.getSource() != pow && event.getSource() != mod)
            {
                start = true;
            }
        }
```

I would expect that if I did 16, then pressed square root and got 4. If I pressed another number, it would clear first, then show the new value put in.

So I'm wondering if there was another way to clear that would work for the scientific buttons.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mre]."

Comment: @c0der see my edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually this line of code that I was missing:

```java
    display.setText("");
```

If I put it in 'start' method, the problem would be solved.